# How do I stop playing bot music? (Discord.js)

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

This code is for playing music, and I want to have a stop command on my bot. Could you help me?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json")
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core")
const streamOptions = {seek:0, volume:1}

client.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return
    if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const comando = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase()

    if(comando === "play") {
        var voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("733122593019789314")
        let file = args[0]

        if(voiceChannel == null) {
            console.log("Canal não encontrado.")
        }

        if(voiceChannel != null) {
            console.log("Canal encontrado.")

            await voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
                const stream = ytdl(file, {filter:"audioonly", quality:"highestaudio"})
                const DJ = connection.play(stream, streamOptions)

                DJ.on("end", end => {
                    voiceChannel.leave()
                })
            }).catch(console.error)
        }

    }/* I was trying to do the command this way:
      else if(comando === "stop") {
        voiceChannel.leave()
    }*/
}

client.login(config.token);
```

Everything works, I just want to stop the music.

(I'm Brazilian, some words or sentences may be wrong.)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StreamDispatcher](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher).[pause](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=pause)() and [StreamDispatcher](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher).[resume](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=resume)().

Your [StreamDispatcher](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher) is defined as `DJ`, so you can use:

```js
DJ.pause(); // Pauses the stream.

DJ.resume(); // Resumes the stream.

DJ.destroy(); // Ends the stream.
```

Comment: Ok, I try to do it but returns me a error saying "DJ is not defined". I tried to change "const" to "var" and it doesn't works.

Comment: Try to define DJ at the beginning of your code like this: `let DJ;`, and change `const DJ = connection.play(stream, streamOptions)` to `DJ = connection.play(stream, streamOptions)`.

Comment: It didn't work. I changed the code but it is still giving me an error... Thanks for your help.

I'm going to the discord.js docs to look for an answer.

I've just thought to use voiceChacnnel.leave() . I'll try it and tell you.

Comment: It worked!!!! I just verify if the command is play or if it is stop. If it is stop, This code runs:                 ```await voiceChannel.leave()```

It's very simple. Thank you!!! 